# MVC EF5 Table column updated by trigger but value not returning

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have defined a column in a SQL Server Table and set its value using an After Insert Trigger. This value is computed based on recently inserted identity. However, I am unable to get this value in the Controller after the database changes are saved.

Here is my (pseudo) code in the controller:

```
var model = new model();

model.column1 = abc;
model.column2 = xyz;
model.column3 = "CC";

// db object below is a model inheriting DbContext

db.table.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();

// Do some operations not related to this table

// Try retrieving value of column3 
// which should have been updated by the after insert trigger

var column3Value = db.table.find(model.id).column3;
```

What aspects of EF5 do I miss here?

Below is my trigger code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SetColumn3]
ON [dbo].[Table]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE Table
    SET Column3 = RTRIM(inserted.Column3) + CAST(inserted.Id + 100 AS nvarchar(10))
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Table.Id = inserted.Id;
END
```

Comment: Can you share your trigger code please

Comment: Have you defined the property as database generated in your mapping (or with data annotation)?

Comment: @RAS - I have added my trigger code above.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - The Id column is defined in my model and uses data annotations [Key] and         [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Answer (score 1):

`Column3` property must be defined with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` if you want to get back data created by your trigger during insertion. This declaration tells EF that the value is created in the database during insertion and that it must query the value.

Comment: I don't want Column3 as identity. It cannot be set as Computed either because I'm setting a value before creating a new record and the after insert trigger updates it further. I want this updated value back in the controller.

Comment: EF doesn't support combination of value set in the application and in the database. It supports only values handled completely in the application or completely in the database. With your current set up you will need to use another context to query the object again (or detach it first from the original context). EF will not pull the new value for you into existing object.